# Macbook Pro semi-frozen

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, performance, force-quit

My mac is in a weird state without particular reason. 
It is awake, but mouse clicks don't work, so I can't open any menus or apps.
If I shut the lid, it locks after a while, but not immediately. When it gets to the locked state, it allows me to log into my account, by typing password, but it won't let me switch user or get to the screen, where I can restart it.

Keyboard is even more weird. It react to all feature buttons (brightness, sound, keyboard brightness), except power button and "app buttons" (f3-f4). It doesn't react to holding power button for 10+ seconds, nor cmd+option+power button shortcut.

I'm able to call "force quit apps" menu via cmd+alt+esc and close all apps and restart finder, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas what should I do?

I can't detach battery, since it 2015 retina model and I don't have correct screwdriver on me.

UPDATE: External mouse and keyboard react the same way

Comment: You may have a bad top case because if you're getting issues while holding down the power button (which is outside of the OS), it's a physical problem.  Try holding for 30 seconds - see if you can force it to power off.  If you can open a Terminal session, issue the command `sudo shutdhown -h now`

Comment: @Allan Thank you for the command, I've used a modified one with r flag to reboot. Seems like it was a software issue, since everything works fine now

Comment: I'm glad it's not hardware!  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I've noticed that all shortcuts work in Finder. Here are my steps, how I fixed the problem:

1. Try to launch finder, by killing rest of the apps via  "force quit apps" menu (`Command+Alt+Esc`)
2. Go to utilities folder (`Shift+Command+U`)
3. Use arrows to select Terminal
4. Open terminal (`Command+Down Arrow`)
5. Issue command `sudo shutdhown -r now`. I decided to use `-r` flag to reboot my mac, in case power button is dead and I won't be able to load it.

Now everything works fine. It was just a software bug.

Answer (score 0):

Some processes may be active behind the typical "force quit apps" menu.

Open the activity monitor, click on "Memory" and see what's commanding most of the resources. For most macs, anything over 1GB of memory will result in too much memory pressure and slow performance.  A short term solution is to "quit" or "force quit" using the X button in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: Good idea, but it was impossible to use activity monitor, since clicking was not available

Answer (score 0):

Try to reboot your computer.

- Hold down the power button for at least 5 seconds (in your case, hold it down for about 30 seconds) if that doesn't work, try the other options below
- Open Terminal and issue the following command to *restart* your computer

  ```
  $ sudo shutdown -r now
  ```
- Also try shutting it down completely, then powering back up with the power button:

  ```
  $ sudo shutdown -h now
  ```

If you can get things back up and running, I highly suggest resetting the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) as it appears to be a power issue.  There are different methods depending on your Mac model so be sure to read the steps carefully.